# MySQL order by $variable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to think of a way to order the results from the highest number to the lowest one.

The problem here is that those numbers will be from a different table and I am not sure how I should do it.

Please check out below.. *
Thanks!

*Edit:

I know that I suck at coding but still :)
What I need is instead of ORDER BY id to be Order by $results (highest number to lower)

Current Code I am using:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE id > 1 AND status = '1' ORDER BY id ASC;";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

for ($i=0; $i < @mysql_num_rows ($result); $i++) { 
$row = @mysql_fetch_array($result); 

$total = $total + 1;
$results = '';
$noinv = '';

$query2 = "SELECT SUM(number) FROM tableb WHERE id = '$row[id]' AND cur = '1' AND type = '1' AND pos = '1';";
$result2 = @mysql_query($query2);
$row2 = @mysql_fetch_array($result2);

if ($row2['SUM(number)'] == '') {
    $row2['SUM(number)'] = '0.00';
}

$query3 = "SELECT SUM(number) FROM tableb WHERE id = '$row[id]' AND cur = '1' AND type = '1' AND pos = '2';";
$result3 = @mysql_query($query3);
$row3 = @mysql_fetch_array($result3);

if ($row3['SUM(number)'] == '') {
    $row3['SUM(number)'] = '0.00';
}

$results = $row3['SUM(number)'] - $row2['SUM(number)'];

print $row['id'].' '.$row['status'].' '.$results;
}
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry about that.. This was my first try around here. I've just added the current code I am using..

Comment: Please let us know the solution you need. Say it in clear words. try to give sample output and table structures. Please consider adding some info and edit your question. That would be helpful for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is unclear, but try to give you general answer

select A.column1,A.column2,A.column3,count(B.*) total

from table A, table B

where A.Id=B.Id

group by A.Id

order by total desc

Comment: I've just added the current code I am using and what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I think you can get your result in one query,remove both queries in loop,and try this query before loop.
SELECT a.*,b.sum(number) total FROM table a,table b WHERE a.id > 1 AND a.status = '1' and a.id=b.id AND b.cur = '1' AND b.type = '1' AND (b.pos='1' or pos = '2') group by a.id ORDER BY total ASC;

Comment: Thank you for the reply mate. I tried that query but no results are coming out. Trying to tune it up atm :)

Comment: Ok I managed to make it work :P As a newbie, took me some time. So what I did was instead of b.sum(number) total needed to be sum(b.number) total and add a b. infront of the second pos :) Thank you once again mate, works awesomely!